# Matlab 2012a with Windows SDK 7.1

Tags: matlab, mex

I am trying to setup the mex compiler. I am on Windows 8 with Visual studio 2012 and Matlab 2012a.

I have already downloaded [Windows SDK 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=8279) and installed:

But when I try to:

```
mex -setup
```

It says:

```
No supported SDK or compiler was found on this computer. 
For a list of supported compilers, see  
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2012a/win64.html
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Windows SDK 7.1 is on the list, so this is probably the Windows SDK installer bug referenced in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Windows SDK 7.1 is on the list of supported compilers, so this is a valid question.

I think it might be [this bug](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-IB1G3Q/), which I have run into where compilers get removed ([details from MS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2519277))!  Check it out [here too](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-G1P8HP/index.html?solution=1-G1P8HP).  The patch is on [Microsoft's website](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4422).

See [this support article](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-FPLDGV/) for tips on how to download and configure the SDK for MATLAB.  Maybe confirm that the compilers were selected in the installation.