# how to implement in matlab with a fortran source code that uses c header files and fortran libraries?

Tags: c, matlab, fortran, shared-libraries, mex

I have a main Fortran code that useses C header files and a Fortran library and the compiled code needs some dll files to be in the same directory. I don't have access to the source code of the Fortran library. I want to implement this in Matlab. I am trying to understand whether this is possible and what steps are required to achieve this. I have my questions below, please let me know if I am heading in he right direction or not. Thanks!

1. Use the MEX files interface in Matlab.
2. Use mex -setup with Fortran compiler to compile the main Fortran code.
3. Use mex -setup with Fortran compiler to use the Fortran library? Can I use the Fortran library with mex at all? I don't have the source code for it.
4. What do I do with the C header files? Do I use mex -setup with a C++ compiler to make use of them?
   Apparently there is an issue with mex -setup in the Visual Studio 10 SDK 7.1 and Matalb 2012, which I am aware of.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With regard to using the Windows SDK 7.1, [there is a bug of which I am aware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19105762/2778484) that can cause `mex -setup` to fail, but it is with the SDK rather than MATLAB.  Once you apply [this fix from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4422), then `mex -setup` will succeed.

If the FORTRAN contains a [mexFunction entry point](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexfunction.html), then you should have no problem building the MEX file (with FORTRAN compiler) by linking with the C library using the headers you have. But, you may have to write a mexFunction if you do not have one. Notice that while there are a variety of compiler+linker configurations for FORTRAN, which you can list with `fLangCompilers = mex.getCompilerConfigurations('Fortran','Supported')`, the linkers are the same `link.exe` of Visual Studio or Windows SDK used with the C and C++ MEX configurations. Therefore, as far as I can tell, you should have no trouble building the MEX function with the FORTRAN code and linking with the C library by simply adding it on to the `mex` command as you would any other library (e.g. `mex -v -largeArrayDims mexFun.F CLib.lib`). For a FORTRAN MEX example:

```
edit([matlabroot '/extern/examples/mex/mexlockf.F']);
```

Essentially, my guess is that the following should work:

1. Ensure you have patched the Windows SDK with the fix linked above.
2. Run `mex -setup` and choose the Intel FORTRAN compiler with SDK linker.
3. Write your MEX file (say mexFun.F) in FORTRAN, including the header for the FORTRAN library, and calling whatever FORTRAN function is declared in the header. OR try building the FORTRAN code into a separate library referencing it from a C mexFunction.
4. Build with `mex -v -largeArrayDims mexFun.F CLib.lib`

It's worth a try~

Comment: I have edited my question for clarity. The main program is in Fortran and I don't have any C codes, but a C header file. So I think that means I need to compile the main Fortran code after mex -setup with a Fortran compiler (instead of number 3 in your answer). Is that correct?

Comment: @ZZZ What source code do you have (not including headers)? Just binaries?

Comment: I have a Fortran source code. The rest is a couple of .lib binary libraries and a couple of C header files.

Comment: Oh, then yeah you'll need the FORTRAN compiler. I had it backwards, but I think the solution is roughly the same.