# Visual Studio 2012 pro and Matlab 2013a

Tags: matlab, visual-studio-2012, simulink, mex

I'm trying to setup the visual studio 2012 compiler with matlab 2013a 64 bits on a Windows 8 64-bits machine, so that I can run a matlab function inside a simulink simulation. I made the mex -setup and mbuild -setup as I found saying in the web, but when I run the simulation, I get an error

```
Unable to locate a C-compiler required by Stateflow and MATLAB Function blocks.
Use 'mex -setup' to select a supported C-compiler.
```

Does anyone have any idea of where could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also had issues getting a supported compiler for 2013a on win 8 (64bit)... For me it was eventually solved with Windows SDK 7.1 which is not supported on win 8 but does work (once you get passed the issues with installation)

Comment: Might be related to [this bug with the SDK installer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19105762/2778484), which graciously deletes all the compilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug (I'm guessing). See the workaround on the MathWorks website:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/bugreports/931218