# Matlab mex can't compile my c/c++ files (windows)

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mex

I have to use a code (which has been written by someone else) which contains c files, c++ files and Matlab files. My version of Matlab is 2013b
The code has been used many times on Linux (probably Ubuntu, not sure though) and is working well. 
I work on windows, I therefore downloaded microsoft SDK 7.1. Then I could do the mex -setup  in Matlab and choose SDK 7.1 as my default compilator. 
Then the problems arise when I try to compile the files (like "mex arrangeBL.c"). I got errors like:

> > arrangeBL.c(15) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
> >     arrangeBL.c(19) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier

And I got like a hundred of it. It doesn't come from the code, since it was used on linux.

If I try to compile C++, the error is different:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\intrin.h(26) : fatal error >C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ammintrin.h': No such file or directory

I tried several things, like updating SDK 7.1, or changing the version of .Net framework, but I can't make it work.

Thanks

Comment: maybe the mex generated is not from the code you are trying to compile. Did you checked the code to see if the errors make sense? undeclared variables and missing ';' are usually easy to spot. If this in fact exist than most probably you are not using the correct code.

Comment: Try SP1 for vs2010: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5.  Also, it could be related to [this bug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19105762/2778484).

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro 
The errors don't make any sense, I tried to run a Hello world program, and I get error like these:
>>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\cmath(19) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'acosf' 

"maybe the mex generated is not from the code you are trying to compile."

Comment: so it should be from the compiler. try the suggestion above and try to mex one of the examples from matlab: matlabroot/extern/examples. As soon as you make this work pass to your code.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the lines of code that result in syntax errors (15 and 19)?

Comment: Just curious, what does this file do? `ammintrin.h` contains intrinsics to use SSE4 vector machine instructions. There will be issues will portability if you use these in functions. First of all, you need a CPU which supports these instructions, and second of all, some compilers require flags to be passed in order to support these instructions. For instance, AVX instructions in gcc require the `-mavx` flag and also require a compiler version that supports these instructions.

Comment: @Mathieu: like others have suggested, you should start by compiling a "hello world" MEX-function. Post the code you tried, the command used to compile it, and the error messages...