# MATLAB R2012b 32bit mex setup cannot find Visual Studio 2010 professional compiler

Tags: visual-studio-2010, matlab, mex

I have MATLAB R2012b 32-bit installed and Visual Studio 2010 Professional (inc. SP1). I also had Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 installed, which I have now removed as I thought it may be causing the issue with no luck.

here is the problem:
My Visual Studio 2010 compiler does not show up on the list when I try to set up a default compiler for mex

```
>> mex -setup

Welcome to mex -setup.  This utility will help you set up  
a default compiler.  For a list of supported compilers, see  
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2012b/win32.html 

Please choose your compiler for building MEX-files: 

Would you like mex to locate installed compilers [y]/n? y

Select a compiler: 
[1] Lcc-win32 C 2.4.1 in C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2012b\sys\lcc 
[2] Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 in C:\LegacyApp\VisualStudio2005 

[0] None
```

None of the few suggestions I found on my search have helped. I have put the \Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin directory in system path, tried [copying "mspdb100.dll" from the "..\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\" to the "..\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\"](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/27759-mex-file-issue#answer_36115), and also removed Windows SDK 7.1 and repaired my VS2010 installation.

Any other recommendations? I am on 64-bit windows 7.

Comment: This bug affects vs2010 as well as the SDK: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19105762/2778484. Try the fixed in that post

Comment: Short answer: [Visual C++ compilers are removed when you upgrade Visual Studio 2010 Professional or Visual Studio 2010 Express to Visual Studio 2010 SP1 if Windows SDK v7.1 is installed](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4422).  If this works, please up vote my [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19105762/2778484). :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apparently the default directory mex was looking in was wrong. Once I provided the correct path to the compiler, it seems to be working fine.