# Matlab 2012b, MEX and Visual C++ 2010: stdio.h "Cannot open include files"

Tags: matlab, mex

I'm running Matlab 2012b on Windows 7 x86.
When doing

```
mex -setup
```

I get

```
Select a compiler: 
[1] Lcc-win32 C 2.4.1 in C:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2012b\sys\lcc 
[2] Microsoft Software Development Kit (SDK) 7.1 in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 
[3] Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
```

and select option 3.
When I then compile some C++ code, the compiler cannot find the stdio.h file:

```
 fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What happens if you select option 2?

Comment: Same thing. Option 1, of course, doesn't work because LCC can only compile C.

Comment: Could you show the output for the failing command when you replace `mex` with `mex -v`?

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/9YaRWmXs

Comment: 2010 likes to get broken.  Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19105551/2778484